# Issue with deploying a flask app to Heroku

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, flask, heroku, selenium-chromedriver

I have flask app that uses Selenium to scrape and display the 1s price of Bitcoin and Ethereum to a webpage. I recently wanted to deploy the code, but I'm just getting H10 errors from Heroku which are application specific errors. The code runs fine locally, but when I try to modify it so It's able to run on Heroku I just get errors which leads me to believe that I'm configuring it wrong or I'm doing something wrong. A few days ago the application was displaying for about 2 min's before crashing. Could it be a memory issue?

Below is my application

Flask app ↓

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from flask import Flask, render_template
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

# Create a new service with the path to the Chromedriver
service = Service(executable_path=os.environ.get("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH"))

driver_ethereum = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
driver_ethereum.get("https://www.binance.com/en/trade/ETH_USDT?_from=markets&theme=dark&type=spot")

driver_bitcoin = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
driver_bitcoin.get("https://www.binance.com/en/trade/BTC_USDT?_from=markets&theme=dark&type=spot")

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/get_price')
def get_price():
    while True:
        ethereum_price = driver_ethereum.execute_script("return document.querySelector('.showPrice').innerText")
        bitcoin_price = driver_bitcoin.execute_script("return document.querySelector('.showPrice').innerText")
        time.sleep(1)
        return f"Ethereum Price: {ethereum_price}, Bitcoin Price: {bitcoin_price}"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

Index page ↓

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block head %}
<title>Crypto Prices</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function updatePrice() {
            $.get('/get_price', function(data) {
                var prices = data.split(', ');
                $('#ethereum_price').text(prices[0]);
                $('#bitcoin_price').text(prices[1]);
            });
        }
        setInterval(updatePrice, 1000); // Update every 1 second
    </script>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div id="center">
    <h1>Current Bitcoin and Ethereum price</h1>
    <p id="ethereum_price">Loading...</p>
    <p id="bitcoin_price">Loading...</p>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Base template file ↓

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Orbitron&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    {%block head%}{% endblock %}

</head>
<body>
    
{% block body %}{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

My Procfile contains ↓
`web: gunicorn app:app`

The requirments.txt file contains all the necessary dependencies

- Contacted Heroku support
- Debugged

Crash log:

```
2023-10-02T13:09:41.884102+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2023-10-02T13:12:13.713518+00:00 heroku[web.2]: State changed from crashed to starting
2023-10-02T13:12:33.280644+00:00 heroku[web.2]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:app`
2023-10-02T13:12:34.075755+00:00 heroku[web.3]: State changed from crashed to starting
2023-10-02T13:12:34.480641+00:00 app[web.2]: [2023-10-02 13:12:34 +0000] [2] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
2023-10-02T13:12:34.480661+00:00 app[web.2]: [2023-10-02 13:12:34 +0000] [2] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:12917 (2)
2023-10-02T13:12:34.480661+00:00 app[web.2]: [2023-10-02 13:12:34 +0000] [2] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2023-10-02T13:12:34.484623+00:00 app[web.2]: [2023-10-02 13:12:34 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
2023-10-02T13:12:34.553021+00:00 app[web.2]: [2023-10-02 13:12:34 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
2023-10-02T13:12:35.015670+00:00 heroku[web.2]: State changed from starting to up
2023-10-02T13:12:44.414203+00:00 heroku[web.3]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:app`
2023-10-02T13:12:45.164126+00:00 app[web.3]: [2023-10-02 13:12:45 +0000] [2] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
2023-10-02T13:12:45.164393+00:00 app[web.3]: [2023-10-02 13:12:45 +0000] [2] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:11982 (2)
2023-10-02T13:12:45.164431+00:00 app[web.3]: [2023-10-02 13:12:45 +0000] [2] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2023-10-02T13:12:45.166699+00:00 app[web.3]: [2023-10-02 13:12:45 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
2023-10-02T13:12:45.203366+00:00 app[web.3]: [2023-10-02 13:12:45 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
2023-10-02T13:12:45.677430+00:00 heroku[web.3]: State changed from starting to up
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251903+00:00 app[web.2]: [2023-10-02 13:12:56 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251928+00:00 app[web.2]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251929+00:00 app[web.2]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 609, in spawn_worker
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251937+00:00 app[web.2]: worker.init_process()
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251937+00:00 app[web.2]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251939+00:00 app[web.2]: self.load_wsgi()
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251939+00:00 app[web.2]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251939+00:00 app[web.2]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251939+00:00 app[web.2]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251940+00:00 app[web.2]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251940+00:00 app[web.2]: self.callable = self.load()
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251940+00:00 app[web.2]: ^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251940+00:00 app[web.2]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251941+00:00 app[web.2]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251941+00:00 app[web.2]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251941+00:00 app[web.2]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251941+00:00 app[web.2]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251942+00:00 app[web.2]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251942+00:00 app[web.2]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 371, in import_app
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251942+00:00 app[web.2]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251942+00:00 app[web.2]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251943+00:00 app[web.2]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251944+00:00 app[web.2]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251944+00:00 app[web.2]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251945+00:00 app[web.2]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251945+00:00 app[web.2]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251945+00:00 app[web.2]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251945+00:00 app[web.2]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251945+00:00 app[web.2]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251945+00:00 app[web.2]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251946+00:00 app[web.2]: File "/app/app.py", line 21, in <module>
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251946+00:00 app[web.2]: driver_bitcoin = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251946+00:00 app[web.2]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251947+00:00 app[web.2]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251947+00:00 app[web.2]: super().__init__(
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251947+00:00 app[web.2]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 56, in __init__
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251948+00:00 app[web.2]: super().__init__(
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251948+00:00 app[web.2]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 205, in __init__
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251948+00:00 app[web.2]: self.start_session(capabilities)
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251948+00:00 app[web.2]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 289, in start_session
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251948+00:00 app[web.2]: response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251949+00:00 app[web.2]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251949+00:00 app[web.2]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 344, in execute
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251949+00:00 app[web.2]: self.error_handler.check_response(response)
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251950+00:00 app[web.2]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251950+00:00 app[web.2]: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251950+00:00 app[web.2]: selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251951+00:00 app[web.2]: (chrome not reachable)
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251955+00:00 app[web.2]: (The process started from chrome location /app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251956+00:00 app[web.2]: Stacktrace:
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251956+00:00 app[web.2]: #0 0x5640f30d26b3 <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251956+00:00 app[web.2]: #1 0x5640f2da81e7 <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251956+00:00 app[web.2]: #2 0x5640f2ddb526 <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251957+00:00 app[web.2]: #3 0x5640f2dd769c <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251957+00:00 app[web.2]: #4 0x5640f2e1a23a <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251957+00:00 app[web.2]: #5 0x5640f2e10e93 <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251957+00:00 app[web.2]: #6 0x5640f2de3934 <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251957+00:00 app[web.2]: #7 0x5640f2de471e <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251957+00:00 app[web.2]: #8 0x5640f3097cb8 <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251958+00:00 app[web.2]: #9 0x5640f309bbf0 <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251958+00:00 app[web.2]: #10 0x5640f30a619c <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251958+00:00 app[web.2]: #11 0x5640f309c808 <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251958+00:00 app[web.2]: #12 0x5640f306927f <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251958+00:00 app[web.2]: #13 0x5640f30c0e88 <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251958+00:00 app[web.2]: #14 0x5640f30c1059 <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251958+00:00 app[web.2]: #15 0x5640f30d1843 <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251959+00:00 app[web.2]: #16 0x7f485e9beb43 <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251959+00:00 app[web.2]:
2023-10-02T13:12:56.251963+00:00 app[web.2]: [2023-10-02 13:12:56 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2023-10-02T13:12:56.363410+00:00 app[web.2]: [2023-10-02 13:12:56 +0000] [2] [ERROR] Worker (pid:8) exited with code 3
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173570+00:00 app[web.3]: [2023-10-02 13:12:57 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173586+00:00 app[web.3]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173588+00:00 app[web.3]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 609, in spawn_worker
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173588+00:00 app[web.3]: worker.init_process()
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173588+00:00 app[web.3]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173589+00:00 app[web.3]: self.load_wsgi()
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173589+00:00 app[web.3]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173589+00:00 app[web.3]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173589+00:00 app[web.3]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173589+00:00 app[web.3]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173590+00:00 app[web.3]: self.callable = self.load()
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173590+00:00 app[web.3]: ^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173590+00:00 app[web.3]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173590+00:00 app[web.3]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173590+00:00 app[web.3]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173590+00:00 app[web.3]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173590+00:00 app[web.3]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173591+00:00 app[web.3]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173591+00:00 app[web.3]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 371, in import_app
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173591+00:00 app[web.3]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173591+00:00 app[web.3]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173592+00:00 app[web.3]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173593+00:00 app[web.3]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173593+00:00 app[web.3]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173593+00:00 app[web.3]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173594+00:00 app[web.3]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173594+00:00 app[web.3]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173594+00:00 app[web.3]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173594+00:00 app[web.3]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173594+00:00 app[web.3]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173594+00:00 app[web.3]: File "/app/app.py", line 21, in <module>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173594+00:00 app[web.3]: driver_bitcoin = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173594+00:00 app[web.3]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173598+00:00 app[web.3]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173598+00:00 app[web.3]: super().__init__(
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173598+00:00 app[web.3]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 56, in __init__
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173598+00:00 app[web.3]: super().__init__(
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173598+00:00 app[web.3]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 205, in __init__
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173598+00:00 app[web.3]: self.start_session(capabilities)
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173598+00:00 app[web.3]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 289, in start_session
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173598+00:00 app[web.3]: response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173599+00:00 app[web.3]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173599+00:00 app[web.3]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 344, in execute
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173599+00:00 app[web.3]: self.error_handler.check_response(response)
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173600+00:00 app[web.3]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173600+00:00 app[web.3]: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173600+00:00 app[web.3]: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"message":"Target crashed"}
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173600+00:00 app[web.3]: (Session info: headless chrome=117.0.5938.132)
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173601+00:00 app[web.3]: Stacktrace:
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173602+00:00 app[web.3]: #0 0x55d41554b6b3 <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173602+00:00 app[web.3]: #1 0x55d4152211e7 <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173602+00:00 app[web.3]: #2 0x55d4152097fd <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173602+00:00 app[web.3]: #3 0x55d415207c2a <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173602+00:00 app[web.3]: #4 0x55d41520806a <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173602+00:00 app[web.3]: #5 0x55d415206ad1 <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173602+00:00 app[web.3]: #6 0x55d4152189c3 <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173602+00:00 app[web.3]: #7 0x55d415206861 <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173602+00:00 app[web.3]: #8 0x55d415208cea <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173603+00:00 app[web.3]: #9 0x55d415207be4 <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173603+00:00 app[web.3]: #10 0x55d41520806a <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173603+00:00 app[web.3]: #11 0x55d415206ad1 <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173603+00:00 app[web.3]: #12 0x55d415212d50 <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173603+00:00 app[web.3]: #13 0x55d415206861 <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173603+00:00 app[web.3]: #14 0x55d415208cea <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173603+00:00 app[web.3]: #15 0x55d415207be4 <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173603+00:00 app[web.3]: #16 0x55d41520806a <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173603+00:00 app[web.3]: #17 0x55d415206ad1 <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173603+00:00 app[web.3]: #18 0x55d41520e1cf <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173603+00:00 app[web.3]: #19 0x55d415206861 <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173604+00:00 app[web.3]: #20 0x55d415208cea <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173604+00:00 app[web.3]: #21 0x55d415207be4 <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173604+00:00 app[web.3]: #22 0x55d41520806a <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173604+00:00 app[web.3]: #23 0x55d415206ad1 <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173604+00:00 app[web.3]: #24 0x55d4151fee72 <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173604+00:00 app[web.3]: #25 0x55d415206861 <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173607+00:00 app[web.3]: #26 0x55d415205f74 <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173608+00:00 app[web.3]: #27 0x55d415205bf3 <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173608+00:00 app[web.3]: #28 0x55d415223272 <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173608+00:00 app[web.3]: #29 0x55d4151f96a9 <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173608+00:00 app[web.3]: #30 0x55d4151f90f8 <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173608+00:00 app[web.3]: #31 0x55d4152933ab <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173608+00:00 app[web.3]: #32 0x55d415289e93 <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173608+00:00 app[web.3]: #33 0x55d41525c934 <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173608+00:00 app[web.3]: #34 0x55d41525d71e <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173608+00:00 app[web.3]: #35 0x55d415510cb8 <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173608+00:00 app[web.3]: #36 0x55d415514bf0 <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173611+00:00 app[web.3]: #37 0x55d41551f19c <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173611+00:00 app[web.3]: #38 0x55d415515808 <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173611+00:00 app[web.3]: #39 0x55d4154e227f <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173611+00:00 app[web.3]: #40 0x55d415539e88 <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173611+00:00 app[web.3]: #41 0x55d41553a059 <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173611+00:00 app[web.3]: #42 0x55d41554a843 <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173611+00:00 app[web.3]: #43 0x7f6483d72b43 <unknown>
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173611+00:00 app[web.3]:
2023-10-02T13:12:57.173767+00:00 app[web.3]: [2023-10-02 13:12:57 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2023-10-02T13:12:57.239346+00:00 app[web.3]: [2023-10-02 13:12:57 +0000] [2] [ERROR] Worker (pid:8) exited with code 3
2023-10-02T13:13:01.864899+00:00 app[web.3]: [2023-10-02 13:13:01 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
2023-10-02T13:13:02.044551+00:00 app[web.3]: [2023-10-02 13:13:02 +0000] [2] [ERROR] Shutting down: Master
2023-10-02T13:13:02.044610+00:00 app[web.3]: [2023-10-02 13:13:02 +0000] [2] [ERROR] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2023-10-02T13:13:02.145028+00:00 heroku[web.3]: Process exited with status 3
2023-10-02T13:13:02.166292+00:00 heroku[web.3]: State changed from up to crashed
Advertisement
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that Chrome and the Chrome driver are installed on the Heroku server?

Comment: @TimRoberts yes